# How do I format a webform to register for events so I can fill it out multiple times without cancelling previous registrations?

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm, participants

We are using a Webform to allow people to sign multiple people up for multiple events.

If someone has registered themselves for event A & B then later decided they want to go to event C & D as well, how would you set up a webform to allow a second submission that doesn't cancel the first registrations?

Currently if I revisit the form all the events are on offer, there is no indication of which events I am already registered for. If I fill in the form to register for C & D (having previously registered for A & B) and do not select A & B also then when I submit the form it cancels my registration for A & B.

If I am registering multiple people for events. eg person A registers person A and person B to go to lunch. Then person C registers person C and person B to go to dinner. Where lunch and dinner are both events that can be registered for on the same form then currently when person C completes the form person be will have their registration for lunch cancelled.

I am using Drupal 7.56, CiviCRM 4.7.27, Webform-CiviCRM 7.x-4.19

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution, it is a setting that was there all along.

On the CiviCRM configuration page under the Event Registration tab there is a section called Registration options. In here there is a checkbox to "Disable unregistering participants from unselected events" if you check that then as it says contacts will not get unregistered from events.

Doesn't show them what they are currently registered for but we are ok with that as they are not going to lose the registration.

[image]